# How can I set a mutable class property in PHP that can be changed by a method?

Tags: php

I am coding a game that allows users to click a button to hit a random bee.

There are three types of bees:

Queen Bees: Have a lifespan of 100 hit points.
• When the Queen Bee is hit, 8 Hit Points are deducted from her lifespan.
• If/When the Queen Bee has run out of Hit Points, All remaining alive Bees automatically run out of hit
points.
• There is only 1 Queen Bee

Worker Bees: Worker Bees have a lifespan of 75 Hit Points.
• When a Worker Bee is hit, 10 Hit Points are deducted from his lifespan.
• There are 5 Worker Bees.

Drone Bees: Drone Bees have a lifespan of 50 Hit Points.
• When a Drone Bee is hit, 12 Hit Points are deducted from his lifespan.
• There are 8 Drone Bees.

I am trying to code a function that subtracts 8 points from the lifespan of a bee every time it is shot. The lifespan of the bee will decrease accordingly, however, so that on every subsequent shooting the method 'hit()' will take a 'lifespan' argument that is 8 points lower than the previous time it is called. At the moment, my programme just calls the 'hit' method with the original number of points for the bee every time (100). Does anyone know how to implement this feature?

Code:

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bees Game</title>
</head>

<style>
    .button {
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
        background-color: #228822;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }

</style>
<body>

<?php

    include('queenbee.php');

    if (isset($_GET['hello'])) {

        echo 'Hello is set';
        runMyFunction();
    }

?>

    <h1>Bee Game</h1>

    <div class="button"><a href='index.php?hello=true'>Hit me</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
  class Bee {


    private $lifespan;

    private $points;


    function __construct($lifespan, $points)
    {
      $this->lifespan = $lifespan;
      $this->points = $points;
    }

    public function hit($lifespan, $points) { // Function used to hit a bee
      $this->lifespan = $lifespan - $points; 
      echo $this->lifespan;
    }

  }






function runMyFunction() {

  $randomNumber = rand(0, 2);
  $bees = ['queen', 'worker', 'drone'];

  echo '<br>' . $bees[$randomNumber];
  if($bees[$randomNumber] == 'queen'){

    if($queencalled != 'yes')
    {
      $queen = new Bee(100, 8); // First time that queen bee is called
    }
    else
    {
      $queen = new Bee($queen->lifespan, 8);
    }
    $queencalled = 'yes';
    $queen->hit(); # NULL

  }

  if($bees[$randomNumber] == 'worker'){

    if($workercalled != 'yes')
    {
      $worker = new Bee(75, 10);
    }
    else
    {
      $worker = new Bee($worker->lifespan, 10);
    }
    $workercalled = 'yes';
    $worker->hit(); # NULL
  }

  if($bees[$randomNumber] == 'drone'){

    if($dronecalled != 'yes')
    {
      $drone = new Bee(50, 12);
    }
    else 
    {
      $drone = new Bee($drone->lifespan, 12);
    }
    $dronecalled = 'yes';
    $drone->hit(); # NULL
  }
}    

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are concepts wrong in the code, I would try to explain all and provide a working version that explains some other concepts.

```
<?php

include('queenbee.php');

if (isset($_GET['hello'])) {

    echo 'Hello is set';

    runMyFunction();
}
?>

<h1>Bee Game</h1>

<div class="button"><a href='index.php?hello=true'>Hit me</a></div>
```

The button will recharge the entire page and clear everything. If you want this button to be *interactive* you have to use javascript (and ajax if you want to execute code from server, like php). Then maybe show the output on a console, or having some graphics to complete the game.

`runMyFunction` is not a good function name, in my example I will call it `main`. Main is a commonly used name of function for pointing where the full program execution starts.

```
public function hit($lifespan, $points) { // Function used to hit a bee
  $this->lifespan = $lifespan - $points; 
  echo $this->lifespan;
}
```

It is better to have this method in the bee that gets hit, since this bee is the **owner** of the information that changes. I would call it `getHit`, since it gets hit by another bee. That bee object provides its hit points as a parameter.

```
public function getHit($points) { // this bee get hit
  $this->lifespan -= $points; 
}
```

A similar version of the following code repeats 3 times, it is better to wrap it in a function having variations as parameters.

```
if($bees[$randomNumber] == 'queen'){

    if($queencalled != 'yes')
    {
      $queen = new Bee(100, 8); // First time that queen bee is called
    }
    else
    {
      $queen = new Bee($queen->lifespan, 8);
    }
    $queencalled = 'yes';
    $queen->hit(); # NULL

  }
```

I figured out what you want to do, and I created a simple game where there are a number of bees of these types, and they hit each other until there is only one alive. This is very usefull and also funny. For now it's a console app instead than a browser application.

Run it in the console and program some tests while programming the main parts of your system. Then when everythings run smoothly is time to go to the browser and have the figure out the full system architecture.

```
<?php
  class Bee {


    private $lifespan;
    private $type;
    private $points;

    // added a parameter to know the bee type
    function __construct($type,$lifespan, $points)
    {
      $this->type = $type;    
      $this->lifespan = $lifespan;
      $this->points = $points;
    }

    public function getHit($points) { // this bee get hit
      $this->lifespan -= $points; 
    }
    // know the number of points
    public function points(){
      return $this->points;
    }

    // get a string version of the bee
    public function __toString(){
      if ($this->isAlive()){
        return "a {$this->type} bee with ".
          str_pad ( $this->lifespan,3," ", STR_PAD_LEFT).
          " of life";     
      }
      return "a {$this->type} dead bee";    
    }

    //know whether it is alive
    public function isAlive(){
        return $this->lifespan > 0;
    }

  }



function main() {

  // extracted the data from the code
  $bees = [
      //type   => [number, lifespain, points]
      'queen'  => [1,100,8], 
      'worker' => [5,75,10], 
      'drone'  => [8,50,12], 
      ];

  // this is the bee pool where all bees are created
  $beePool = [];

  // create all bees
  foreach($bees as $type => $data) {

    for($i=$data[0]; $i>0; $i--){
        $beePool[] = new Bee($type,$data[1],$data[2]);
    }
    echo "created $data[0] $type bees".PHP_EOL;  
  }
  echo PHP_EOL;

  // let them fight
  while (count($beePool)>1){

      $beeNumber = count($beePool);
      // get a bee from the beePool
      $attacked  = rand(0, $beeNumber-1);
      $attacker  = rand(0, $beeNumber-2);
      // fix the number so it wont be the same bee 
      // and will get the full range of valid bees
      if ($attacker >= $attacked){
          $attacker ++;
      }
      echo "The bee #$attacker will atack the bee #$attacked".PHP_EOL;
      $attBee = $beePool[$attacker];
      $hitBee = $beePool[$attacked];

      echo "ATTACKER: ".$attBee.PHP_EOL;
      echo "    HITS: ".$hitBee.PHP_EOL;
      $hitBee->getHit($attBee->points());
      // remove dead bee
      if (!$hitBee->isAlive()){
         echo "AND IT DIES".PHP_EOL. $beeNumber-1 ." bees alive".PHP_EOL;
         array_splice($beePool, $attacked, 1);
      }
      echo PHP_EOL;
      sleep(1);
  }

  echo "The remaining bee is ".$beePool[0];

}    

main();
```

And it outputs:

```
created 1 queen bees
created 5 worker bees
created 8 drone bees

The bee #1 will atack the bee #5
ATTACKER: a worker bee with  75 of life
    HITS: a worker bee with  75 of life

The bee #9 will atack the bee #10
ATTACKER: a drone bee with  50 of life
    HITS: a drone bee with  50 of life

The bee #7 will atack the bee #5
ATTACKER: a drone bee with  50 of life
    HITS: a worker bee with  65 of life

[...]
The bee #2 will atack the bee #1
ATTACKER: a drone bee with  30 of life
    HITS: a worker bee with  11 of life
AND IT DIES
2 bees alive

The bee #0 will atack the bee #1
ATTACKER: a queen bee with  36 of life
    HITS: a drone bee with  30 of life

The bee #0 will atack the bee #1
ATTACKER: a queen bee with  36 of life
    HITS: a drone bee with  22 of life

The bee #0 will atack the bee #1
ATTACKER: a queen bee with  36 of life
    HITS: a drone bee with  14 of life

The bee #1 will atack the bee #0
ATTACKER: a drone bee with   6 of life
    HITS: a queen bee with  36 of life

The bee #0 will atack the bee #1
ATTACKER: a queen bee with  24 of life
    HITS: a drone bee with   6 of life
AND IT DIES
1 bees alive

The remaining bee is a queen bee with  24 of life
```

Answer (score -1):

You aren't passing any parameters when you call your hit() function, but you are defining that function with parameters in your class.  You don't need those parameters since they are already defined in the constructor.

```
public function hit() { // Function used to hit a bee
  $this->lifespan -= $this->points; 
  echo $this->lifespan;
}
```